# (ORACLE/SQL) Insert into when

Tags: sql, oracle

The example would be:

```
Declare
stringtest VARCHAR2(10):='yes';
Begin
INSERT WHEN (condition) THEN   -- the condition has to be like stringtest='yes';
INTO ...
Select ...
End;
```

But I can't do it like

```
Begin
INSERT WHEN TRUE THEN
INTO ...
Select ...
End;
```

What is the easiest way to let the condition be true?

Comment: move you condition to the Select... where clause.

Comment: `insert into some table select ... where stringest = 'yes'`

Answer (score 1):

the easiest (and the right) way is to move condition into select 'where' clause. If select returns (selects) nothing, then nothing will be inserted.
i.e.

```
insert into table(col1,col2)
select 'colval1', 'colval2'
from dual
where 2=3
```

will select nothing and insert nothing

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SQL (as opposed to PL/SQL) doesn't have a boolean type, so `TRUE` isn't recognised in the SQL statement (standalone, or if it happens to be within a PL/SQL block).

You can use a dummy expression that always evaluates to true, e.g.:

```
INSERT WHEN (1=1) THEN
INTO ...
Select ...
```

[Quick SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68587/1).

Unless this is a 'fixed' part of a larger `INSERT ALL` construct, the clause seems rather redundant if you know it always has to be true; if you aren't evaluating something real, the `WHEN` clause isn't adding anything useful. If you want to use it as a flag to control the behaviour then your `stringtest` approach would probably be easier since you can change that setting in one place - in the declare section - rather than hunting through and changing all the individual `WHEN` clauses.